# How to get value from array having index keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working in `PHP` back-end. I have doubt on array. How to get values from array using index values.

**Example :**

```
$array = [
    "FirstName"=>"Ram",
    "LastName"=>"R",
    0 => "Developer",
    1 => array()
]
```

I have records similar to above example.my array containing some key=>value pairs and some index based values. my doubt is how to get all values from array having normal index.

**Expection output:**

```
$newArray =[Developer,array()]
```

Comment: Define normal index...

Comment: what u mean by normal index???

Comment: if index will get increase what can i do

Comment: So you basically **just** want the values that have numeric indexes then, pushed into a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_filter()` and only return values where the corresponding key is integer:

`$o = array_filter($array, "is_int", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

#### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/pq4sf)

Comment: my answer and this has a same output .. I go with the flow and billyonecan ue the function that the difference :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?php echo $array['FirstName']; ?>
```

or if you're feeling fancy,

```
<?= $array['FirstName']; ?>
```

You use `$var['key']` / `$var[index]` to obtain the value of that key/index.

Comment: i dont have key.i have only index value.if i have more values in table index should increase

Comment: key, index, same difference. `$array[index]`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code u can have your all key and value..

```
$array = [
    "FirstName"=>"Ram",
    "LastName"=>"R",
    0 => "Developer",
    1 => array('a','b')
];
foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
  //echo "key : ".$key ;
  if(is_numeric($key)){
      echo "yes"; // here i just echo u can add them into separate array!!! 
    }
  //echo "value : ".$value ;
}
```

after that u can modified or checked whether the key is normal or not ..

Comment: i need values as array. which having index as key

Comment: Thanks for your support. i got output from above answers

Comment: yaah but  some one down vote my answer :( mine is also right just u have to write some more code in if condition plz upvote atlease :)